# Failed to start Unicorn application server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn, systemd

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to set up a Rails server, but when I try to start the unicorn application server I encounter this error:

```
$ sudo service unicorn_appname start
Job for unicorn_appname.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status unicorn_appname.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

More details:

```
$ systemctl status unicorn_appname.service
● unicorn_appname.service - LSB: starts the unicorn app server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-11-23 20:22:36 UTC; 1min 33s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 39284 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 23 20:22:36 azure systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts the unicorn app server...
Nov 23 20:22:36 azure unicorn_appname[39284]: /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname: 30: cd: can't cd to /home/deploy/appname
Nov 23 20:22:36 azure systemd[1]: unicorn_appname.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 23 20:22:36 azure systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: starts the unicorn app server.
Nov 23 20:22:36 azure systemd[1]: unicorn_appname.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 23 20:22:36 azure systemd[1]: unicorn_appname.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried typing these error messages on google but none gave any helpful results, and I'm kind of stuck now because I'm a total beginner with Rails and setting up web servers in general. Any tips?

Comment: `Nov 23 20:22:36 azure unicorn_appname[39284]: /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname: 30: cd: can't cd to /home/deploy/appname`  check path if exist and application file are accessible, permissions and etc.

Comment: PRINT these lines of your config

# app settings
USER="deploy"
APP_NAME="appname"
APP_ROOT="/home/$USER/$APP_NAME"
ENV="production" ????

Comment: @num8er pointed me in the good direction (I forgot to replace the author's user by mine in a configuration file), but I have other problems now so later I'll update the question or post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments the problem was in this line:

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname: 30: cd: can't cd to /home/deploy/appname
```

In the tutorial there is a file called `/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname` and I forgot to replace the user of the author (`deploy`) by mine. Later I encountered another problem. Same immediate output, different answer by `systemctl` but it all came down to this line:

```
bundler: command not found: unicorn
```

I solved it by installing the dependencies of my project globally:

```
sudo bundle install
```

I don't know if this is the best option and I still don't know if the overall system will work as a whole because I haven't configued `nginx` yet but I had no error messages from the command `sudo service unicorn_appname start`. Other answers are welcomed.